# Youtube iframe player api fires event END only at end of playlist

Tags: javascript, iframe, pyqt, youtube-javascript-api

After checking again and again I noticed that if I load a playlist with:

```
player.loadPlaylist(videoCodeList, start);
```

Then I don't get ENDED events fired after each video in the playlist ends, but only in the end of the playlist itself.

In cases of a single video playlist the ENDED event is fired at the end of the video.
Why is that if any one noticed that? 
What I'm trying to achieve is to stop a video at its end, if a user asked to play only
 single song, even if it is part of a playlist.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="player"></div>
  <script>
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var videoCodeList = playlistObject.getCodeList();

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          playerVars:{rel:0, showinfo:0},
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
            ,'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }

        });
      }


      function onPlayerReady(event) {
          var start = playlistObject.getStart();
          player.loadPlaylist(videoCodeList, start);

      }


      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
          if (event.data == 0 && playSingle.findChecked()){
              player.stopVideo();


        }
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>""")
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope my question was pointing a real problem after i checked it again and again for hours with no solution.
I also posted a 'report a bug' undere 'issue 6408' hopefully reporting a real existing problem.

For the meantime i made a workaround to this problem:
I added a signal/slot connection ,inside javascript code, using QtWebKit bridge technology:(playSingle is an QAction exposed to javascript code)

```
playSingle.toggled.connect(playCurrentOnly);
```

playSingle action triggers signal-toggled, each time a toolbar button is pressed for choosing 'Play Single Song'.
And added the 'playCurrentOnly' function to handel this signal inside javascript code:

```
function playCurrentOnly(){
      var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
      player.stopVideo();
      player.seekTo(currentTime, true);
```

It works fine with just a slight short pause before continuing playing the song.